# Are there specific examples of integral polyhedra that are neither Totally Unimodular nor Total Dual Integral?

Tags: co.combinatorics, linear-programming

It is well known that if a constraint matrix $A$ is total dual integral or totally unimodular, then this is a sufficient condition of integrality of the polyhedron defined by the system $Ax \leq \beta$ (provided that $\beta$ has integer entries). But it is not a necessary condition.

Thus my question is

> Are there *natural* examples (from combinatorial optimization) of integral polyhedra such that their underlying constraint matrix is neither TUM nor TDI?

Comment: By "underlying constraint matrix" do you mean the natural matrix defined by the facets of the polyhedron? Or are you just asking for a matrix $A$ that is not totally unimodular nor total dual integral but such that, for some $b$ (or do you want it to hold for all $b$?) $\{x : Ax \leq b\}$ is an integral polytope?

Comment: Also, I don't think TUM and TDI are standard enough abbreviations that it is good to use them in your title...

Comment: @JoshuaGrochow As for your first question, I actually ask for both: an example of an integral polyhedron where we cannot formulate it as a TUM/TDI matrix A for any vector b. As for the abbreviations, I will change them.

Comment: I don't think such a thing exists. I believe Giles and Pulleyblank showed that any integral polytope can be written as $\{x : Ax \leq b\}$ for some total dual integral A and integer vector b.

Comment: @JoshuaGrochow That's a bit surprising to me. So, TDI is  a necessary _and_ sufficient condition for integrality? If so, why it is  mentioned only as sufficient condition?

Comment: Because TDI is a property of a system of linear in equations specified by a pair (A, b), it is not a property of a polytope. For such a system to define an integral polytope, it suffices for the system to be TDI, but there are non-tdi systems that also define integral polytopes.

Comment: @JoshuaGrochow Thanks for the comments. So, a given TDI system (A,b) defines an integral polytope. That is fine and known. You claim than there are non-TDI systems that define integral polytopes. And my question is which are these polytopes, any reference for that? Same for TUM. Also, in this context, I do not understand the reference to Giles&Pulleyblank (that any integral polytope can be written as a TDI system). I am missing something but I do not know what..

Comment: I still don't think it's a question of "which are those polytopes", since TDI isn't a property of polytopes. Every integral polytope can be written as the solution set of some TDI system. I bet it's not hard to show that every integral polytope can also be written as the solution set of some non-TDI system: you can probably do this by taking an arbitrary linear system that defines $P$ and if it is TDI then just scale it by a random rational number; see the proof of Thm 3.2 in Giles-Pulleyblank.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm only going to talk about the constraint matrix part of the problem, I don't know much about the linear system (TDI) part.

Call a matrix $A$ **good** if $\{x|Ax\leq b,x\geq 0\}$ is a integral polytope for all integral $b$.
TUM is precisely the set of good integral matrices. This is a result by Hoffman and Kruskal. [see this](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007%2F978-3-540-68279-0_3#page-1) for how the theorem comes about and the original paper.

If we relax the requirement that $A$ is integral, then we get a larger class of matrices. Call a good matrix $A$ trivial, if it is a scaling of a TUM matrix (i.e. $A=\frac{1}{k}B$ for some TUM matrix $B$ and integer $k$).

Sadly, I don't know of any *natural* non-trivial good matrices.

But there is a characterization of good matrices. A matrix $A$ is *$1$-regular* if for all non-singular square submatrix $R$, $R^{-1}$ is integral. We have the [following by Appa and Kotnyek](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0012365X03000955).

> A rational matrix $A$ is good iff $A$ is $1$-regular.

Here is an example of a non-trivial good matrix.

$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 \frac{1}{2} & -\frac{1}{2} \\
 -\frac{1}{2} & -\frac{1}{2} \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

Comment: Τhank you for the answer and the references that I was not aware of! This, together with @JoshuaGrochow comment about TDI, answer my question.